# Two partial responses on the page

Tags: spring, primefaces, websphere, jsf-2.2, spring-webflow-2

please help me. I'm suffering from the situation when I have two partial responses on the page. When I use Tomcat, it's ok, just one response without any additional redirects. It occurs when I use WebSphere application server (WAS 8.5) and try to export to excel:

```
    <p:commandButton id="export"
                        value="#{msg['button.OK']}"
                        action="#{dataExporter.exportAsXls()}"
                        onclick="PF('exportWarningDialoguePanel').hide();"
                    process="@this" partialSubmit="true"/>
```

Response (on WAS 8.5) is:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes><update id="j_idt144:j_idt145"><![CDATA[ bla bla bla]]></update>
    <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[e11s1]]/>
</changes>
</partial-response>
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <redirect url="/app/admin/inbox"></redirect>
</partial-response>
```

Tomcat's response is:

```
<partial-response id="j_id1">
    <changes><update id="j_idt144:j_idt145"><![CDATA[ bla bla bla]]></update>
    <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[e11s1]]/>
</changes>
</partial-response>
```

Is it a WAS config issue?

Comment: Check in your code where a redirect to `/app/admin/inbox` might be done. Not something that WAS 'invents' by itself. Might be login/authentication related

Comment: @Kukeltje Hi, thanks for your comment. Well, redirect maybe provided by Spring Web Flow, but strange that it happens only in case of WAS. Explicitly there are no any redirects.

Comment: Find the differences in url it runs on etc. Disable sppring webflow...etc...  Next to impossible to help besides 'guessing'